# XMLHttpRequest 400 Bad request during AJAX call on second request

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have some weird issue in which during `AJAX` call in `MVC` with POST method it will return `400 BAD Request` randomly after second / third call on server but in local system it works properly.

I have pass same parameter during each call but randomly it will return `400 error` on server.

Below is my `AJAX` call code:

```
function RunSimulation() {
ShowProgress();
var url = GetDomainURL() + "/Project/RunSimulation";
var data = $("form").serialize();
var random = Math.random();
alert('multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8; boundary='+random);
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
async: false,
cache: false,
    contentType: 'multipart/form-data;charset=UTF-8; boundary='+random,
    // timeout: 60000 * 10,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('sucess');
        HideProgress();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        HideProgress();
    }
});
}
```

I have stuck in this issue in last 2 days so please help me if anyone have any idea on this.

Below is my request body

```
__RequestVerificationToken=n96WSaViL9XKPZZArj0aqnGTxMGts5P5OJxO9-PdgcJUjoB3HKcK3_LPHa4I3IbDDModNpFl6RLxDSrr7eYOmIBOzQS99NSUyF6V9Zl-wtMVRaVPU_KomFXie58t8EjEhNhCHGxcM-9V-bZHC0_8twzFxaEkef6lwOtbhGfIx7E1&TabIndex=5&SubmitIndex=0&Mode=&ProjectHeader.ProjectHeaderId=79&SiteInformation.CalculateAnnualPercentage=False&SiteInformation.IsOSRSizing=True&ProjectHeader.SiteCount=2&hdnUserType=2&hdnUserOSR=True&ProjectHeader.ProjectHeaderId=79&ProjectHeader.Region=1&ProjectHeader.Country=Canada&ProjectHeader.State=AB&ProjectHeader.ProjectName=Test+Project&ProjectHeader.City=&ProjectHeader.ProjectNumber=79&ProjectHeader.DominantLand=2&ProjectHeader.OtherState=&ProjectHeader.ProjectDate=09%2F09%2F2015&ProjectHeader.ProjectDesignBy=vaibhavi+pandya&ProjectHeader.Notes=&ProjectHeader.FirstName=vaibhavi&ProjectHeader.LastName=pandya&ProjectHeader.Email=vpandya%40conteches.com&ProjectHeader.PhoneNumber=878-787-8787&ProjectHeader.Company=ei&ProjectHeader.EORFirstName=&ProjectHeader.EORLastName=&ProjectHeader.EOREmail=&ProjectHeader.EORPhoneNumber=&ProjectHeader.EORCompany=&SiteInformation.RainFallStationName=EDMONTON&SiteInformation.RainFallStation=1&SiteInformation.RainFallStationName=EDMONTON&SiteInformation.RainFallStationState=Alberta&ManageRainFallStation.RainFallStationFilter.State=Alberta&ProjectHeader.Country=Canada&ManageRainFallStation.RainFallStationFilter.SelectedCountry=&ManageRainFallStation.RainFallStationFilter.Location=&SiteInformation.PeakRainfallIntesityCkecked=false&SiteInformation.PeakRainfallIntesityCkeckedValue=0.00&StationState=&SiteInformation.ProjectHeaderId=79&SiteInformation.SiteId=127&SiteInformation.SiteName=Site+1+&SiteInformation.SiteArea=5&SiteInformation.Imperviousness=60.0&SiteInformation.TSSRemoval=80.0&SiteInformation.peakConvey=&SiteInformation.RunOff=&SiteInformation.WQF=&SiteInformation.IsOilPara=False&SiteInformation.OilParaValue=&SiteInformation.Width=447.00&SiteInformation.Slope=2&SiteInformation.ImperviousD=0.518&SiteInformation.PerviousD=5.08&SiteInformation.ImperviousM=0.015&SiteInformation.PerviousM=0.25&SiteInformation.MaxI=61.98&SiteInformation.MinI=10.16&SiteInformation.DecayRate=0.00055&SiteInformation.RegenerationRate=0.01&SiteInformation.DailyEvap=2.54&SiteInformation.Flow=0&SiteInformation.Freq=12&SiteInformation.FilterationWinterMonthsChecked=false&SiteInformation.WinterStartMonth=&SiteInformation.WinterEndMonth=&SiteInformation.InletInvertElev=&SiteInformation.PipeDiameter=&SiteInformation.OutletInvertElev=&SiteInformation.PipeMaterial=&SiteInformation.RimElev=&SiteInformation.IsMultipleInlets=False&SiteInformation.WaterLevelElev=&SiteInformation.IsGrateInlet=False&SiteAttenuationManage.ManageSiteAttenuationList%5B0%5D.Flow=0.00000&SiteAttenuationManage.ManageSiteAttenuationList%5B0%5D.Storage=0.00000&SiteAttenuationManage.ManageSiteAttenuationList%5B0%5D.IsDeleted=False&SiteInformation.UpstreamFlowDiversionValue=0.00000&SiteInformation.ParticleDistribution=5&SiteInformation.IsRainfallOSRAuthorized=False&SiteInformation.IsUserOSRAuthorized=False&SiteInformation.NoNullIsOSRSizing=True&SiteInformation.NoNullIsOSRSizing=true&SiteInformation.NoNullIsOSRSizing=false&SiteInformation.IsFlocc=true&SiteInformation.IsFlocc=false&SiteInformation.Flocc=20&ManageTSSFunction.ManageTSSFunctionList%5B0%5D.Name=Build+Up%2F+Wash-off&ManageTSSFunction.TSSRblValue=1&ManageTSSFunction.ManageTSSFunctionList%5B1%5D.Name=Event+Mean+Concentration+(EMC)&ManageTSSFunction.ManageTSSFunctionList%5B2%5D.Name=Power+Wash-off&ManageTSSFunction.ManageTSSFunctionList%5B3%5D.Name=Power+Wash-off+(Winter+Only)&SiteInformation.BuilUpPower=0.40&SiteInformation.ExpoWashOff=0.20&SiteInformation.TargetEvent=125.00&SiteInformation.AvailabilityA=0.05&SiteInformation.AvailabilityB=0.04&SiteInformation.AvailabilityC=1.10&SiteInformation.PSAvailability=400.00&SiteInformation.PowerWashOffFactor=0.08&SiteInformation.PowerWashExp=1.15&SiteInformation.PWWinterStartMonth=1&SiteInformation.PWWinterEndMonth=1&SiteInformation.EMC=444.00&SiteInformation.WinterSand=&SiteInformation.SandingStartMonth=&SiteInformation.SandingEndMonth=&WinterPSDMappingManage.ManageWinterPSDHeaderList%5B0%5D.ParticleDiameter=0.00&WinterPSDMappingManage.ManageWinterPSDHeaderList%5B0%5D.Percentage=0.00&WinterPSDMappingManage.ManageWinterPSDHeaderList%5B0%5D.SpecialGravity=0.00&WinterPSDMappingManage.ManageWinterPSDHeaderList%5B0%5D.IsDeleted=False&SiteInformation.CalculateAnnualPercentage=false&SiteInformation.RecommendedModel=OSR+4000%0D%0A&SiteInformation.SiteId=127
```

Comment: Why are your using the `boundary` parameter and why are you using `async: false,`?

Comment: I just try difference options to resolved issue but no luck and also removed boundry parameter and put async: true but still get same issue.

Comment: what returns from GetDomainURL()

Comment: @Janina - It's just set full URL so based on publish directory structure it will add domain name.

Comment: are you requesting to another domain?

Comment: @janina - Thanks for your support and i figured out issue by putting server side log in controller method and it was due to file write issue at server side and it will now resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was hinted at in comments, but why are you setting `Content-Type` to use `multipart/form-data`? You are not sending `multipart/form-data`, you are sending `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data. There is no "multipart" attachment, so no boundary is required.

Try removing altogether the `contentType` line in your ajax call; the `Content-Type` will default to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`, which is what is needed.

Also, better use `async: true` otherwise your page will be unresponsive while it blocks waiting for a response to the ajax request - unless that's what you want.

I am not sure that this is the cause of the 400 bad request errors, but at least this removes one possibility.

Comment: I have removed contentType line and use async: true but still get same result

Comment: @KushalPatel: at least you now know that that is not the problem - although it would probably cause some problem.

Comment: @KushalPatel: The next thing to do is look at the sever logs.

Comment: I have commented all logic at server side controller method and just return view still same error.

Comment: Are there multiple servers involved?, e.g. are requests load balanced between 1 or more servers? If so are all the servers equivalent? That might explain why you get seemingly random results.

Comment: Thanks for your support and i figured out issue by putting server side log in controller method and it was due to file write issue at server side and it will now resolved.

Answer (score 0):

I have use below code as per your suggestions during AJAX Call

```
function RunSimulation() {
ShowProgress();
var url = GetDomainURL() + "/Project/RunSimulation";
var data = $("form").serialize();
var random = Math.random();    
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'POST',
    data: data,
async: true,
cache: false,       
    // timeout: 60000 * 10,
    success: function (data) {
        alert('sucess');
        HideProgress();
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        HideProgress();
    }
});
```

}

But still get error as shown below

[Bad Request Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbDkK.png)